# How do I create a joomla website for a restaurant that has multiple store locations?

Tags: joomla, e-commerce, multistore

I have a Joomla site.I want to make an order page for 4 stores at different locations. My client doesn't want to pay for any plugin. I don't have budget either. I have tried three plugins - Virtuemart, hikashop and j2cart. Please guide me if I can achieve the wanted result with the free version of the plugins or by programming or any way.

Comment: data from 2 plugins can be seen in order and menu pages. Please help - Urgent

Comment: I've been trying this for a long time.

Comment: You question is a little unclear Francis. I assume you want to have a separate section of your website for each restaurant. I cannot understand the payment issue - do you want clients to order and pay online?

Comment: Yes. I mean the user can select for which branch he is placing the order.